# Rails 5 render a template located outside of the 'views' directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The following code

```
def show
  render File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'themes', 'default_theme', 'template'), layout: File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'themes', 'default_theme', 'layout')
end
```

Works in rails 4.2.x but outputs the following error when using Rails 5.0.0

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
 Missing template vagrant/app/themes/default_theme/template with {:locale=>[:nl], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby]}. Searched in:
   * "/vagrant/app/views/themes/default_theme"
   * "/vagrant/app/views"
   * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/devise-ebe65b516b38/app/views"
   * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-i18n-1.1.0/app/views"
```

It looks like it is searching only inside the 'app/views/*' directory. Is there a way to render a template located outside of the 'views' directory using rails 5.0.0, so it works just like it used to in previous Rails versions?

Answer (score 3):

Start by appending the view path:

```
class ApplicationController
  prepend_view_path( Rails.root.join('app/templates') )
  # ...
end
```

You can then render templates in `app/templates` by calling:

```
render template: 'default_theme/template', 
       layout: 'default_theme/layout'
```

Using the `template` option tells rails to not append the path with the name of the controller.

Comment: Got the template working by using the `prepend_view_path` method. This doesn't seem to work for the layout though. Got it working by overwriting a rails function

Comment: Did you get an exception that tells you where rails is looking for the layout?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the new folder to your configuration:

```
config.paths["app/views"].unshift(Rails.root.join("/vendor/myapp/views/myctrl").to_s)
```

Or your controller:

```
before_filter {
prepend_view_path(Rails.root.join("vendor/myapp/views/myctrl").to_s)
}
```

[source](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/rubyonrails-talk/12ce3x9qpk/rails-how-to-add-additional-path-for-views-location)