# How to use a Angular view in a Rails 5 project?

Tags: angular, ruby-on-rails-5

I have found some articles and questions that explain how to use Angular with Rails (see: [Getting Started with Ruby on Rails 5.1.4 and Angular 2+](https://www.techiediaries.com/ruby-on-rails-5-angular-2/)  and [Get Started with Angular 4 and Rails 5](https://www.codewithjason.com/getting-started-with-angular-and-rails/). Unfortunately thats not really what I am looking for because this is just the other way around.

Currently I have a quite big RoR 5 app where I'd like to replace some views and within that rails app a simple Angular app (running on port 4200) with a view.

Is this even possible? Can I run a normal rails application (not a rails API) and get a view from an Angular app?

I've already tried some things, for example [render a view outside of actions](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions) or [render a template located outside of the 'views' directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065805/rails-5-render-a-template-located-outside-of-the-views-directory)
, but I didn't get a working solution.

Example:
When visiting 'http://localhost:3000/products' I do not want to render the corresponding view from rails ('products/index.html.erb') but a html file from the angular project within the rails app (the file is called 'product-list.component.html' and lives in Rails.root/frontend/src/app/product-list/, where frontend is the angular project).

In products_controller I overwrite the view path as follows:

```
    prepend_view_path(Rails.root.join("frontend/src/app/product-list/").to_s)
```

and try to get the view like that:

```
  def index
    # @products = Product.all

    renderer = ApplicationController.renderer.new(
      http_host: 'localhost:4200',
      https:      false
    )

   renderer.render file: "#{Rails.root}frontend/src/app/product-list/product-list.component.html"
 end
```

But then, I get the following error:

```
Missing template home/ramona/Dokumente/tutorials/angular-ror5-appfrontend/src/app/product-list/product-list.component.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/ramona/Dokumente/tutorials/angular-ror5-app/app/views" * "/home/ramona/Dokumente/tutorials/angular-ror5-app" * "/"
```

I hope I explained it in an understandable way. If not, please tell me so I can work on my explanation.

It would be really nice if someone could help me! Or at least tell me if it is possible or not :)

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Templates in angular are rendered in the browser (javascript) and not in the server (the exception is if you are using universal angular, but this is another approach). Usually the rails app (or other app) will only serve data via an API do the frontend, the angular app, that will request these data via ajax requests. So the rails application will never do this "renderer.render file:" in an method. It will usually render a json. Something like render @products.to_json

Comment: I know how to do it the other way around (use Angular as frontend and rails as backend). So from your answer I suggest that there's no way to use some angular views in a rails app?

Comment: You can't use angular views inside a rails app, because rails does not know how to handle angular templates. A view in angular is the "junction" of the component (.ts), style (.scss) and the template itself (.html). Angular is javascript, Rails is ruby.

Comment: I've just found two articles: https://github.com/amitai10/rails-angular-webpacker and https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-vs-angular-2-integration-with-rails, so it looks to me that it would be possible (but it still does not work). How about the other approach, Universal Angular? Do you know whether it is possible to use rails with universal angular? I've found only some examples using express.

Comment: You need node in order to use Universal Angular, because it need a javascript engine to render templates (and do other stuff).